# Syntax Error (?) on jQuery-ui Tabs: Mismatching Fragment Identifier

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to create a jquery-ui tabs box, and I'm getting a "Mismatching Fragment Identifier" error.  I know that means that the href address in the /li/ elements is not matching the id in the /div/ elements.  Problem is that I've been staring at this for a while now and can't find my syntax error.  Can anyone help?

```
<div id="tabmenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href='#Fifth Fleet'>Fifth Fleet</a></li>
    <li><a href='#Eighth Fleet'>Eighth Fleet</a></li>
    <li><a href='#Ninth Fleet'>Ninth Fleet</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='Fifth Fleet'>
    <p>Some Test Junk Here</p>
</div>
<div id='Eighth Fleet'>
    <p>Some Test Junk Here</p>
</div>
<div id='Ninth Fleet'>
    <p>Some Test Junk Here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Spaces are invalid characters.  Code works as written in the question when the spaces are removed from "Fifth Fleet", "Sixth Fleet", and "Eighth Fleet."